# jQuery return [object Object] but dev tool response get what I want

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

In my controller have `actionGetRandomCode`. Why when I shown with jQuery like this

```
var ran = $.get('index.php?r=registrations/get-random-code');
alert(ran);
```

Its getting show `[object Object]`?
But in my dev tool response I get what I want `RQLGLS`

Comment: [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) + [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1)

Comment: alert should be forbidden in javascript

Comment: not just alert. when shown to table `$('#sampleTbl tbody').append('<tr><td>' + ran + '</td></tr>');` Its show `[object object]` too

Comment: You need to use .done and put the alert inside it. The Ajax methods are asynchronous so you need to use a callback function to resolve the result. Read up on promises

Comment: thank its work `var ran = $.get('index.php?r=registrations/get-random-code').done(function(data) { alert( "Data: " + data ); });` @vbranden

Comment: Please get urself familiar to use console.log().Its developer's friendly. At least for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .done and put the alert inside it. The Ajax methods are asynchronous so you need to use a callback function to resolve the result

```
var ran = $.get('index.php?r=registrations/get-random-code').done(function(data) {
    alert( "Data: " + data );
});
```